# Sorting integer array with foreach in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, foreach, int

So I got this school assignment:

> Write a method to take two integer arrays and sort `x[]` into `y[]` using foreach loop.

`x[]` is size 10 and has all elements initialized with `Math.random()`, and `y[]` is of size >10 and filled with zeroes. The method should sort the `x[]` array into `y[]` and `return y[]`.

Since I'm only left with foreach I can't figure a way to refer to other elements in the array in order to compare them. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by ”Since I'm only left with foreach I can't figure a way to refer to other elements in the array in order to compare them.” ?

Comment: Java has a sort of foreach statement `for (E elem : collection) {}` but are you SURE you have to use it?

Comment: @RaulGogo: I was looking for a way to do something like I would with a classic for loop: 'if(x[i] < x[i+1]) //swap the elements' but I would need a counter for that, which I do not have in the foreach.

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a `double` and you're sorting `Integers` - how do you plan to convert `double` to `int` ?

Comment: You can cheat by using a counter you manually increment, and perform a simple insertion sort.

Comment: I wouldn't even say the problem is the comparison. If by 'using only foreach' you're meant not to access the arrays by index (otherwise, it's kind of cheating since the foreach would only be extraneous fluff), how are you supposed to write to y at all? Either the requirements are unclear or you misread them.

Comment: You cannot sort arrays using for-each loop since any sorting algorithm requires keeping track of positions of two given elements of the array. for-each is just a short-hand of iterating through an array in the traditional way.

Comment: @alfasin I've already taken care of that by type casting, problem is the sorting algorithm itself.

Comment: @ViktorHronec casting isn't enough since all the results you'll get from `Math.random()` are between 0.0 to 1.0 ...

Answer (score 2):

This is my 100% serious answer.

```
public static void completelyLegitSort(int[] x,int[] y){
    for(int n:x){
        System.arraycopy(x, 0, y, 0, x.length);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(y);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You are a genius! But be polite, you aren't allowed to change the array x! :D

Comment: Why do you call `java.util.Arrays.sort(y);` inside the for-loop (x.length times) instead of one call right after the loop ?

Comment: @alfasin : the loop breaks after the first iteration

Comment: @alfasin : Zane and I are just joking about the oddity of the teacher's exercise. Basically, he/she is asking a student to screw something with a hammer. We accepted the challenge, and enjoyed finding dirty workarounds to do the exercise. Zane was more disdainful than me.

Comment: @gd1 I understand :) but why not just use lines 3-4 from Zane's answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] crazySort(int[] x, int[] y) {

    System.arraycopy(x, 0, y, 0, x.length);

    int i = 1; // cheating
    for (int n : y) { // <- this is your foreach, you will never use the n variable :D
        if (i == x.length) break; // cheating again
        for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) { // finally doing something reasonable
            if (y[j+1] < y[j]) {
                int temp = y[j+1];
                y[j+1] = y[j];
                y[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return y;

}
```

Hope the teacher finds it funny, at least as funny as the exercise statement. This solution uses the java "foreach" loop, and the exercise statement doesn't tell you to use *only* it.

Comment: `int[] x = new int[]{15,10,7,1,7,6,27,8,2,17};
int[] y = new int[10];

int index;
int count;
for (int i1 : x) {
    index = 0;
    count = 0;
    for (int i2 : x) {
        if(i2 < i1) {
            index++;
        } else if (i2 == i1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    while (count != 0) {
        count--;
        y[index] = i1;
        index++;
    }
}`
Sorry for the formatting. A friend of mine finally figured it out.

Comment: The solution of your friend seems 'hacky' enough to get a good mark. :P Change the name of the variables, put a couple of useless counters and you're done.